# PHP json Scanning escaped character

Tags: php, json, escaping

I am writing a `JSONScanner` class that basically takes a string and scans the whole thing to construct a `JSONObject`. Currently I'm writing `read_string()` method, to read a string. When reading a string that escapes '\', I get some invalid output.

Here is my `JSONScanner` class

```
class JSONScanner {
    private $in;
    private $pos;

    public function __construct($in) {
        $this->in = $in;
        $this->pos = 0;
    }

    #########################################################
    ############### Method used for debugging ###############
    #########################################################
    public function display() {
        $this->pos = 1;
        echo $this->read_string($this->get_char());
    }
    #########################################################
    #########################################################

    private function read_string($quote) {
        $str = "";

        while(($c = $this->get_char()) != $quote) {
            if($c == '\\') {
                $str .= $this->get_escaped_char();
            } else {
                $str .= $c;
            }
        }

        return $str;
    }

    private function get_escaped_char() {
        $c = $this->get_char();

        switch($c) {
            case 'n':
                return '\n';
            case 't':
                return '\t';
            case 'r':
                return '\r';
            // display the characters being escaped
            case '\\':
            case '\'':
            case '"':
            default:
                return $c;
        }
    }

    private function get_char() {
        if($this->pos >= strlen($this->in)) {
            return -1; // END OF INPUT
        }

        return substr($this->in, $this->pos++, 1);
    }
}
```

Here is my running code

```
$str = '{"a\\":1,"b":2}';
$jscan = new JSONScanner($str);
$jscan->display();
```

With the above string, I'm getting

```
a":1,
```

However when I try

```
$str = '{"a\\\":1,"b":2}';
$jscan = new JSONScanner($str);
$jscan->display();
```

I get what I need, which is

```
a\
```

Why am I needing to put 2 backslashes to escape 1 backslash?

EDIT:

I was trying the same json string on `json_decode`, and it gave me the same results, with 2 backslashes, nothing but with 3 backslahes it gave me `a\`. Why is that? Isn't escaping a backslash takes 2 consecutive ones `\\`?

Comment: A JSON scanner? Like a ["parser"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) of sorts? That would be neat!

Comment: @Anthony yes, like a parser, so basically it takes a string which contains a json object, and I scan through it, like Java's `Scanner` class.

Comment: so the string could be invalid as JSON but have a valid JSON string inside it and it would trim off the bad part and parse?

Comment: I'm not handling any bad parts or invalid json yet, I am currently writing each function alone and testing it to make sure it works

Comment: what's wrong with php's `json_encode` and `json_decode` functions?

Comment: I want to try to learn processing strings on my own without using built-in functions, sort of a practice for myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str = '{"a\\":1,"b":2}';
```

This is a PHP string literal, which has its own escaping rules. The actual string you're representing with the above is:

```
{"a\":1,"b":2}
```

If you want to represent *one* backslash in a PHP string literal, you need to write *two* backslashes. So the correct string representation for what you want is:

```
$str = '{"a\\\\":1,"b":2}';
```

It happens to work with three backslashes, because `\\` becomes one `\` and the next `\` isn't followed by any special character, so it by itself also represents a single backslash.